# Select all text on focus

Tags: javascript

I'm creating the front side of a cloud server client. I want to add a possibility to create a new folder. So when I click the button "New Folder", I'm creating and adding un element, which will be the new folder. I'm making it's name "contenteditable" and I put it on focus so the user can change the name of the new folder. What I can't find a way to do is when the element is on focus, automatically select all the text. Has anyone idea how to do that?

I have tried to use .select() but, or it doesn't recognized the function or it says that the element is undefind.

This is the success of my ajax function:

```
        var results = JSON.parse(data);
        var path = results[0];
        var idFolder = results[1];
        var nameFolder = results[2]

        // Create a card of the new Folder
        var column = document.createElement("div");
        column.setAttribute("class", "column");
        column.setAttribute("name", path); // We use it to add or delete element to avoid refresh. We dont't have it for now in Google Drive

        var container = document.createElement("div");
        container.setAttribute("class", "container");

        var card = document.createElement("div");
        card.setAttribute("class", "card");
        card.setAttribute("id", path);
        card.setAttribute("data-serviceid", serviceIdDropBox);
        card.setAttribute("data-serviceemail", serviceEmailDropBox);
        card.setAttribute("data-size", null);
        card.setAttribute("title", nameFolder);

        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.setAttribute("src", "/icons/iconfinder_folder.png");
        image.setAttribute("onclick", "loadDataDropbox('" + serviceIdDropBox + "','" + serviceEmailDropBox + "','" + path + "')");

        var name = document.createElement("div");
        name.setAttribute("title", nameFolder);
        name.setAttribute("data-toggle", "tooltip");
        name.setAttribute("data-placement", "bottom");
        name.setAttribute("id", idFolder);
        name.setAttribute("onclick", "Rename('" + idFolder + "', '" + path + "')");
        name.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
        name.style.width = "100px";
        name.innerText = nameFolder.substring(0, 10);


        var row = document.getElementById("allData");

        // append the elements
        card.appendChild(image);
        card.appendChild(name);
        container.appendChild(card);
        column.appendChild(container);

        row.insertBefore(column, row.children[0]); // or row.firstChild

        var contentWindow = document.getElementById("contentWindow");

        // append "allData" div to the column
        contentWindow.appendChild(row);



        renameNodeNewFolder = document.getElementById(idFolder);

        renameNodeNewFolder.setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
        renameNodeNewFolder.focus();
        renameNode = renameNodeNewFolder;
```

I whant when I create the New Folder it's defaut name to be on focus, selected and ready to be edited.

Comment: It doesn't work in my case.

Comment: "or it says that the element is undefind." - There's the problem I'd be interested in helping you solve. There's no reason I can think of for `.select()` not to work. Trying it on a bad reference to an object is entirely trivial to fix generally. I will not help to write a work-around for someone that can't locate the correct element. That's the problem here as far as I'm concerned - your inability to locate the required element. That's a simple mistake and coding around it, rather than fixing it would be a travesty! (In my not-so-humble opinion)

Comment: As much as that i knew. The right element is that one with the focus. Why it doesn't work? If i knew i wouldn't write here to listen "not so humble opinions". But i know that if you knew how to help you would. Thanks anyway.